# Access specific frame via Watin

Tags: c#, frame, watin

I am trying to enter text, but Watin can't find the correct textbox. I think this is because it's in a frame, and not on the main page. The URL I'm using is https://customerservice.southerncompany.com/NonSecure/LoginFrames.aspx

I have found a workaround for this particular site, but I'll need to get into frames for other sites. Here's what I'm trying to use on this site:

```
browser.TextField(Find.ById("ctl00_MainContent_txtUsername")).TypeText("FakeUsername");
browser.TextField(Find.ById("ctl00_MainContent_txtPassword")).TypeText("FakePassword");

browser.Image(Find.ByName("ctl00$MainContent$btnLogin")).Click();
```

Comment: Are you sure that is the correct name for the textbox?  Are the controls even listed in the DOM?  What is the work-around that you have found for it?  Have you tried using `broswer.Image(FindByName("ctl00_MainContent_txtUserName")).TypeText("FakeUsername");`

Comment: my workaround is to go to https://webauth.southernco.com/login.aspx?WL_Type=E&WL_AppId=OCC&WL_ReturnMethod=FV&WL_Expire=1&WL_ReturnUrl=https%3a%2f%2fcustomerservice.southerncompany.com%2fNonSecure%2flogin.aspx%3fredirect%3dY, which is basically the frame I want as its own page.

Comment: I don't know that that is wise.  At any point are you going to need to use the AttachTo() method?

Comment: I don't know what the AttachTo() method is.

Comment: [AttachTo()](http://watinandmore.blogspot.com/2010/01/browserattachto-and-iattachto.html) in WatiN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply get the frame by using this command

```
Frame frame = browser.Frame(Find.ByClass("yourClassName")); //or by id or name...
frame.TextField(Find.ById("ctl00_MainContent_txtUsername")).TypeText("FakeUsername");
//and etc...
```

Comment: I inspected the mark up for the page, I didn't see any reference to a frame.

Comment: Look for this: <iframe style="width:595px;height:450px" marginheight="32" frameborder="0" src="login.aspx?">
    </iframe>

Comment: I found it just after leaving my comment.  English is not my friend today :)

Comment: In your case there is no class or name for this frame so you can use browser.Frames[0] because this is the only one that exists in this page

Comment: This works for the page in question, but I just tried it on another page that includes frames within a frameset and it does not work. Is there a way to get into the frameset?

Comment: Try this one:  ElementCollection elements = browser.ElementsWithTag("frame", null); this will return you all frames in the page (as elements).